# How to achieve Multicolumn glossaries with header description within a header?

Tags: formatting, glossaries

I am currently having problem to write acronyms with multiple columns and column header. I have managed to write acronyms with column headers only, but can't figure out how to write them in multiple columns. This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany]{report}


 \usepackage[breaklinks,draft]{hyperref}


 \usepackage[acronym,section,nopostdot,nonumberlist,nogroupskip,nostyles] 
 {glossaries}

 \usepackage{glossary-mcols}

 \makeglossaries

 \begin{document}

 \newglossaryentry{cur}{name=cur, description={Just a random name.}}

 \newglossaryentry{mmee}{name=mmee, description={Just a random name.}}

 \newglossaryentry{fsda}{name=fs, description={Just a random name.}}

 \newglossaryentry{dcsc}{name=ddad, description={Just a random name.}}

 \newglossaryentry{ccs}{name=adax, description={Just a random name.}}

 \newglossaryentry{ccc}{name=acDc, description={Just a random name.}}

 \newglossaryentry{vfvv}{name=gegfvv, description={Just a random name.}}

 \newglossaryentry{fvafv}{name=gdgdfv, description={Just a random name.}}

 \newglossaryentry{bgbb}{name=gegvf, description={Just a random name.}}

 \newglossaryentry{gfvfv}{name=qefrwfav, description={Just a random name.}}


 \gls{cur}

 \gls{mmee}

 \gls{fsda}

 \gls{dcsc}

 \gls{ccs}

 \gls{ccc}

 \gls{vfvv}

 \gls{fvafv}

 \gls{gfvfv}

 \gls{bgbb}

 \printglossary[style=mcolindex,title=List of Acronyms]


 \end{document}
```

The output is: 
[image: current picture]

But I want my result as:
[image: desired result]

Comment: A new question isen't needed. You can edit your question. Same [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/380218/124842). I will vote to close the other question, without MWE. Please make sure, that everyone could `copy-and-paste-and-compile` your code.

Comment: Unrelated to the actual problem, but to avoid other things going wrong, put just your `\newacronym` commands into another file (without `\printglossary` and `\chapter` stuff) and [`\input` it in the preamble](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:docdefs). Delete the `.glsdefs` file and rebuild.

Comment: Why do you want to duplicate each entry? Won't that just confuse people? I could understand if you wanted floppy disk alongside compact disk, rather than below it, for a 4 column setup, but I don't understand why you'd want 2 copies of each entry.

Comment: I'm assuming you're not actually wanting to duplicate entries, but are just trying to demonstrate two columns of tabulated material.  In which case, you can't use `longtable` in a multi-column context (neither `twocolumn` mode nor with `multicols`). The simplest solution is if you're happy to have the entries read across the columns (first entry followed by second entry in the same row, then move to the next row for the third entry etc).

Comment: Kindly see the changes and give some directions towards the solution @Nicola Talbot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to have a `long` version of an `mcols` style. The `longtable` environment isn't permitted inside a `multicols` environment nor can it be used in `twocolumn` mode (either with `\twocolumn` or as a class option).

The simplest way to implement it would be to have a `longtable` with four columns (as two pairs of Acronym & Description):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany]{report}

 \usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage[breaklinks,draft]{hyperref}
 \usepackage[acronym,section,nostyles,entrycounter] 
 {glossaries}

 \makeglossaries

\newlength\descwidth
\setlength{\descwidth}{0.25\textwidth}
\renewcommand*{\glsentrycounterlabel}{}%

\newglossarystyle{pairedtable}%
{%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
   {\begin{longtable}{l>{\raggedright}p{\descwidth}l>{\raggedright}p{\descwidth}}}%
   {\end{longtable}}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
    \bfseries \entryname & \bfseries
    \descriptionname &
    \bfseries \entryname & \bfseries
    \descriptionname
    \tabularnewline\endhead
   }%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}% no letter group headings
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}% no gap between letter groups
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &
    \glossentrydesc{##1}% number list omitted
    \ifodd\value{glossaryentry}\def\next{&}\else\def\next{\tabularnewline}\fi
    \next
  }%
  \renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{\glossentry{##2}{##3}}%
}

 \newglossaryentry{cur}{name=cur, description={Just a random name.}}

 \newglossaryentry{mmee}{name=mmee, description={Just a random
name.}}

 \newglossaryentry{fsda}{name=fs, description={Just a random name.}}

 \newglossaryentry{dcsc}{name=ddad, description={Just a random
name.}}

 \newglossaryentry{ccs}{name=adax, description={Just a random
name.}}

 \newglossaryentry{ccc}{name=acDc, description={Just a random
name.}}

 \newglossaryentry{vfvv}{name=gegfvv, description={Just a random
name.}}

 \newglossaryentry{fvafv}{name=gdgdfv, description={Just a random
name.}}

 \newglossaryentry{bgbb}{name=gegvf, description={Just a random
name.}}

 \newglossaryentry{gfvfv}{name=qefrwfav, description={Just a random
name.}}

 \begin{document}


 \gls{cur}

 \gls{mmee}

 \gls{fsda}

 \gls{dcsc}

 \gls{ccs}

 \gls{ccc}

 \gls{vfvv}

 \gls{fvafv}

 \gls{gfvfv}

 \gls{bgbb}

 \printglossary[style=pairedtable,title=List of Acronyms]

 \end{document}
```

Unfortunately the ordering is wrong since the table is constructed by row:

[image: Image of glossary: the alphabetical ordering goes from left to right.]

There's no easy way to get `makeindex` to sort the entries to ensure top to bottom ordering. If you only have a small number of entries you could do the ordering manually and use `glossaries-extra`'s `\printunstglossary` (since you don't want a number list). Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany]{report}

 \usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage[breaklinks,draft]{hyperref}
 \usepackage[acronym,section,nostyles,entrycounter] 
 {glossaries-extra}

\newlength\descwidth
\setlength{\descwidth}{0.25\textwidth}
\renewcommand*{\glsentrycounterlabel}{}%

\newglossarystyle{pairedtable}%
{%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
   {\begin{longtable}{l>{\raggedright}p{\descwidth}l>{\raggedright}p{\descwidth}}}%
   {\end{longtable}}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
    \bfseries \entryname & \bfseries
    \descriptionname &
    \bfseries \entryname & \bfseries
    \descriptionname
    \tabularnewline\endhead
   }%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}% no letter group headings
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}% no gap between letter groups
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &
    \glossentrydesc{##1}% number list omitted
    \ifodd\value{glossaryentry}\def\next{&}\else\def\next{\tabularnewline}\fi
    \next
  }%
  \renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{\glossentry{##2}{##3}}%
}

 \newglossaryentry{ccc}{name=acDc, description={Just a random
name.}}
 \newglossaryentry{fvafv}{name=gdgdfv, description={Just a random
name.}}
 \newglossaryentry{ccs}{name=adax, description={Just a random
name.}}
 \newglossaryentry{vfvv}{name=gegfvv, description={Just a random
name.}}
 \newglossaryentry{cur}{name=cur, description={Just a random name.}}
 \newglossaryentry{bgbb}{name=gegvf, description={Just a random
name.}}
 \newglossaryentry{dcsc}{name=ddad, description={Just a random
name.}}
 \newglossaryentry{mmee}{name=mmee, description={Just a random
name.}}
 \newglossaryentry{fsda}{name=fs, description={Just a random name.}}
 \newglossaryentry{gfvfv}{name=qefrwfav, description={Just a random
name.}}

 \begin{document}


 \gls{cur}

 \gls{mmee}

 \gls{fsda}

 \gls{dcsc}

 \gls{ccs}

 \gls{ccc}

 \gls{vfvv}

 \gls{fvafv}

 \gls{gfvfv}

 \gls{bgbb}

 \printunsrtglossary[style=pairedtable,title=List of Acronyms]

 \end{document}
```

[image: Image of glossary: entries ordered from top to bottom pairwise.]

This isn't particularly convenient if you have a lot of entries. An alternative is to construct side-by-side `tabular` environments, but you'll have to determine the correct number of rows. In the example below, I've loaded test entries provided with the `glossaries` package to pad the glossary:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany]{report}

 \usepackage{array}
 \usepackage[breaklinks,draft]{hyperref}
 \usepackage[acronym,section,nostyles]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\loadglsentries[\acronymtype]{example-glossaries-acronym}% dummy entries

\newlength\descwidth
\setlength{\descwidth}{0.25\textwidth}

\newcounter{rowcount}

\newglossarystyle{table}%
{%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
   {%
    \setcounter{rowcount}{0}%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{l>{\raggedright}p{\descwidth}}%
    \bfseries \entryname & \bfseries
    \descriptionname \tabularnewline
   }
   {\end{tabular}}%
   \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}% no letter group headings
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}% no gap between letter groups
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \stepcounter{rowcount}%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &
    \glossentrydesc{##1}% number list omitted
    \ifnum\value{rowcount}=25 % 25 entries per column
      \def\next{%
        \end{tabular}\hfill
        \setcounter{rowcount}{0}%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l>{\raggedright}p{\descwidth}}%
        \bfseries \entryname & \bfseries
        \descriptionname \tabularnewline
      }%
    \else
      \def\next{\tabularnewline}%
    \fi
    \next
  }%
  \renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{\glossentry{##2}{##3}}%
}

 \begin{document}
 \glsaddall

 \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=table,title=List of Acronyms]

 \end{document}
```

[image: image of glossary]

Comment: Thank You so much @Nicola Talbot. My problem is solved now.