# Increase space between multicolumn glossaries in LaTeX

Tags: glossaries

I really like the custom glossary style below! My MWE is attached as well.
How can I increase the space between the two columns?

**More precisely:**
I would like to increase the space between "Absatz" and "BGB". Currently it looks a bit squeezed to me. Moreover I want to include a header above each of the two columns. More like "Acronym" and "Description". Is this easy to implement?

May you help me? Thank you very much in advance!!!

,Max

---

**Minimal work example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, BCOR=12mm, 12pt, numbers=noendperiod, ngerman]{scrbook} 
\usepackage[nopostdot, toc, sanitize=none]{glossaries} %sanitize={symbol=false} %nogroupskip
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}

\newlength\acrwidth
\appto\newacronymhook{%
  \settowidth{\acrwidth}{\textsc{\the\glsshorttok}}%
  \addtolength{\acrwidth}{1em}%
  \ifdim\acrwidth>\glstreeindent
    \setlength{\glstreeindent}{\acrwidth}%
  \fi
}
\setacronymstyle{long-sc-short}

\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
  \setglossarystyle{mcoltree}%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \hangindent\glstreeindent\relax
    \parindent0pt\relax
    \makebox[\glstreeindent][l]{%
       \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}}%
    \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space##2\par
  }%
}

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}


\newacronym{BAG}{BAG}{Bundesarbeitsgericht}    %some dummy entries

\newacronym{BAGE}{BAGE}{Sammlung der Entscheidungen vom Bundesarbeitsgericht}

\newacronym{GewO}{GewO}{Gewerbeordnung}

\newacronym{BetrVG}{BetrVG}{Betriebsverfassungsgesetz}

\newacronym{Abs}{Abs.}{Absatz}

\newacronym{ArbS}{ArbStättV}{Arbeitsstättenverodnung}

\newacronym{vgl}{vgl.}{vergleiche}

\newacronym{ff}{f./ff.}{folgende, \textit{meint nachfolgenden Inhalt}}

\newacronym{Urt}{Urt.}{Urteil}

\newacronym{BGB}{BGB}{Bürgerliches Gesetzbuch}

\newacronym{LAG}{LAG}{Landesarbeitsgericht}

\newacronym{BZgA}{BZgA}{Bundeszentrale für gesundheitliche Aufklärung}

\newacronym{RKI}{RKI}{Robert Koch-Institut}

\newacronym{BAuA}{BAuA}{Bundesanstalt für Arbeitsschutz und Arbeitsmedizin}

\newacronym{GG}{GG}{Grundgesetz für die Bundesrepublik Deutschland (Verfassung)}


\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\ihead{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\begingroup
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{0.82\linewidth}
\printglossary[
type=\acronymtype,                  % glossary overview
nonumberlist,                       % No page numbering for glossary
title=Abkürzungsverzeichnis,
toctitle=Abkürzungsverzeichnis,     % title in toc
style=mystyle
]
\glsaddall
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/380321/134144 could be related and probably interesting.

Comment: this thread didn't solve my problem. Is there anyone out there who can edit my code mentioned above? I would be so grateful because I have to submit my thesis within the next two weeks.

Comment: It yould be really helpful if you could provide the definition of some dummy abbreviations as your MWE currently is nunfortunately not compilable due to the missing definitions. With thouse it is a lot easier for others in order to test possible solutions.

Comment: thanks and sorry for that. I just edited my post. Now you can see some dummy entries.

Comment: is there anyone out there wo knows how to fix this issue? Greetings from germany!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the spacing between the columns by changing `\columnsep`.

```latex
\documentclass[oneside, BCOR=12mm, 12pt]{scrbook} 
\usepackage[nopostdot, toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}

\newlength\acrwidth
\appto\newacronymhook{%
  \settowidth{\acrwidth}{\textsc{\the\glsshorttok}}%
  \addtolength{\acrwidth}{1em}%
  \ifdim\acrwidth>\glstreeindent
    \setlength{\glstreeindent}{\acrwidth}%
  \fi
}
\setacronymstyle{long-sc-short}

\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
  \setglossarystyle{mcoltree}%
  \columnsep 3em
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \hangindent\glstreeindent\relax
    \parindent0pt\relax
    \makebox[\glstreeindent][l]{%
      \glsentryitem{##1}\glstreenamefmt{\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}}%
      \ifglshassymbol{##1}{\space(\glossentrysymbol{##1})}{}%
    }%
%    \glstreepredesc
    \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space##2\par
  }%
}

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\newacronym{BAG}{BAG}{Bundesarbeitsgericht}
\newacronym{BAGE}{BAGE}{Sammlung der Entscheidungen vom Bundesarbeitsgericht}
\newacronym{GewO}{GewO}{Gewerbeordnung}
\newacronym{BetrVG}{BetrVG}{Betriebsverfassungsgesetz}
\newacronym{Abs}{Abs.}{Absatz}
\newacronym{ArbS}{ArbStättV}{Arbeitsstättenverodnung}
\newacronym{vgl}{vgl.}{vergleiche}
\newacronym{ff}{f./ff.}{folgende, \textit{meint nachfolgenden Inhalt}}
\newacronym{Urt}{Urt.}{Urteil}
\newacronym{BGB}{BGB}{Bürgerliches Gesetzbuch}
\newacronym{LAG}{LAG}{Landesarbeitsgericht}
\newacronym{BZgA}{BZgA}{Bundeszentrale für gesundheitliche Aufklärung}
\newacronym{RKI}{RKI}{Robert Koch-Institut}
\newacronym{BAuA}{BAuA}{Bundesanstalt für Arbeitsschutz und Arbeitsmedizin}
\newacronym{GG}{GG}{Grundgesetz für die Bundesrepublik Deutschland (Verfassung)}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\printglossary[
  type=\acronymtype,
  nonumberlist,
  title=Abkürzungsverzeichnis,
  toctitle=Abkürzungsverzeichnis,
  style=mystyle
]
\glsaddall

\end{document}
```

However, this makes your description columns very small. I believe that you should rethink this style.

---

For the column headings, you will really have to use a `longtable`-based style instead of a `multicolumn`-based one. Since you are effectively faking a table using hanging paragraphs anyways, I think that is a good option for you. In this case, the [answer linked by leandriis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/380321/48973) has what you need.